# Scanner input not working when used in a While loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method to validate a user input to be "1". Therefore I used a while loop for validation. Yet, it enters the while loop when the input is "1".

```
public static int switchInput() {

    System.out.print("\n" + "Enter your selection: ");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String selection = userInput.next();

    while (selection != "1" /*&& selection != "2" && selection != "3"*/){

        System.out.println("Enter 1: ");
        //System.out.println("Please enter either '1','2' or '3': ");
        selection = userInput.next();

    }

    int result = Integer.parseInt(selection);
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
What would you like?
1: Regular Hamburger
2: Healthy Burger
3: Deluxe Burger

Enter your selection: 
1
Enter 1: 
1
Enter 1: 
1
Enter 1: 

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: !selection.equals("1") use this instead of selection != "1".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selection != "1"` is wrong. `!=` checks for reference inequality i.e. if the objects on both sides are not same, then the condition will return `true`.

In your case, `selection` and String object with value `1` are different objects, that's why the condition is returning true.

Instead, use `!selection.equals("1")`

**Edit:**

As suggested by [Igor Nikolaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530351/igor-nikolaev), if there is no compulsion of using `String` object as a choice, you could use `int selection = userInput.nextInt()` for getting selection as `int`. In that case, you can use `selection == 1`.

Comment: Alternatively it's possible to use `int selection = userInput.nextInt()` since you expect user to enter a number and you still parse the string into number afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @IgorNikolaev. I have included your point in the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You see, the variable `'selection'` is a string, and to compare two string using `!=` is incorrect.
Instead, use the method `equals()`
So I see you want to compare the String selection and a string "1" replace the if condition with:

```
while(!selection.equals("1")){
```

TIP: You expect the user to input a number, so why make selection a string? It would be better if it was an int.